# Run container in a remote podman is failing

Tags: podman

I am trying to run a "remote"-like podman service, and it works for building and pulling images, but not for running containers.

I've started a podman service by running

```bash
docker run --privileged -p 8888:8888 quay.io/podman/stable:latest podman system service --time=0 tcp://0.0.0.0:8888
```

Afterward I add a connection to my local podman client

```bash
podman system connection add local tcp://localhost:8888
```

And this works, I can connect to the client, and I can pull

```bash
(venv) richardnemeth@Richards-MBP-2 workspace % podman pull alpine:latest
Resolved "alpine" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull docker.io/library/alpine:latest...
Getting image source signatures
Copying blob sha256:b3c136eddcbf2003d3180787cef00f39d46b9fd9e4623178282ad6a8d63ad3b0
Copying blob sha256:b3c136eddcbf2003d3180787cef00f39d46b9fd9e4623178282ad6a8d63ad3b0
Copying config sha256:6e30ab57aeeef1ebca8ac5a6ea05b5dd39d54990be94e7be18bb969a02d10a3f
Writing manifest to image destination
Storing signatures
6e30ab57aeeef1ebca8ac5a6ea05b5dd39d54990be94e7be18bb969a02d10a3f
```

and list images

```bash
(venv) richardnemeth@Richards-MBP-2 workspace % podman image list
REPOSITORY                TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED      SIZE
docker.io/library/alpine  latest      6e30ab57aeee  2 weeks ago  5.56 MB
```

However when I try to run a container, I get an error

```bash
(venv) richardnemeth@Richards-MBP-2 workspace % podman run docker.io/library/alpine echo hello
Error: error preparing container e672734a4e53a77cbf92a39486df2aa49cb0824c0f9224e5010494f5de830b77 for attach: crun: writing file `/sys/fs/cgroup/libpod_parent/libpod-e672734a4e53a77cbf92a39486df2aa49cb0824c0f9224e5010494f5de830b77/cgroup.procs`: Operation not supported: OCI runtime error
```

and the podman service container also has a log

```bash
time="2022-06-11T11:35:31Z" level=warning msg="Failed to add conmon to cgroupfs sandbox cgroup: error creating cgroup path /libpod_parent/conmon: write /sys/fs/cgroup/cgroup.subtree_control: device or resource busy"
```

Any idea what is going wrong? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug in podman, it is now fixed in https://github.com/containers/podman/pull/14787